# pull all docker images in saltstack

Tags: docker, salt-stack

I would like to pull all tags from a Docker registry with SaltStack.

To pull all tags from a specific registry in Docker you can use: docker pull --all-tags user/registry

In SaltStack I'm using dockerng but:

- with image.present I can't specify to have all tags present.
- With dockerng.pull user/registry I also can't specify to pull all
  tags.

Any help would be appreciated :)

---

Alternatively I could pull a specific tag from the registry if I would know which tags are available. As far as I know it's not possible to see which tags are available in the registry....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without diggin into dockerng state at all. You can always achieve this using the [cmd.run state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.cmd.html):

```
docker pull --all-tags user/registy:
  cmd.run
```

Nevertheless i usually prefer using the states like you tried. If this case is not covered yet, you might file an issue in saltstack and solve it for now using `cmd.run`.

Comment: I'm currently using cmd.run and share with you that it would be nice to have this possibility in SaltStack's dockerng.
Thanks for your input!